# JDBC connectivity using ruby not jruby

Tags: ruby, jdbc

Is there any gem available to Connect to JDBC DB2 for the Ruby project. I have come across activerecord-jdbc-adapter but it works only for Jruby.

Also can i use Jruby specific gem in Ruby? I have Ruby 2.2 and Jruby 9.0.0 in my machine

Comment: I doubt it, since JDBC is... Java. Ruby isn't. Why do you need to use JDBC instead of just connecting to DB2 directly? And same for JRuby-specific gems: they're JRuby-specific by definition. You *might* be able to if it's not relying on the J part of JRuby.

Comment: Thanks.. can you please share me the DB2 gem detail for Ruby or any other useful link if you have already come across.

Comment: I just searched for "Ruby DB2" or "Ruby DB2 ActiveRecord" or something and it came right up.

Comment: Thanks Dave Newton. posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it using two other gems which was mentioned in one site.

We need Sequel and ibm_db gems and ran the below code, it worked

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'
require 'ibm_db'

Sequel.connect("ibmdb://#{username}:#{password}@#{db_url}") do |db|
  db.fetch(selectquery) do |row|
    puts row
  end
end
```

Comment: The ibm_db thing is not JDBC-based, it used the ODBC/CLI driver for IBM Db2, and is a native Ruby adapter for Db2.